# Automate TortoiseGit with switch options

Tags: git, automation, tortoisegit

I am trying to automate TGit for source control.  I have read their documentation and it only gets me partially there.  What I am after is not only calling the dialogs, but also prefilling them.  I don't see any switches for the many dialogs used.  Has anyone done this before?
For instance, I want to automate the merge dialog and git it where to merge from.  I cannot find these types of switches.

Comment: FWIW in TortoiseSVN i was able to do this.  Now i am trying to do the same thing with Git.

Answer (score 1):

The possible options for TortoiseGit are documented here: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-automation.html

As of 2.6.0 it is not possible to pre-fill the dialog from the CLI.

There is also noted:

> Remember that TortoiseGit is a GUI client, and this automation guide shows you how to make the TortoiseGit dialogs appear to collect user input. If you want to write a script which requires no input, you should use the official Git command line client instead.

Comment: The reason i want to use Tortoise is that it has an awesome conflict resolver for when merges or stash pops fail.  If i could simply put in the merge branch to the dialog and click the OK button, it would make my entire operation automated.  this is my last piece